# how to fix with a nested json loop whose output is [object Object]

Tags: jquery, fetch

So I'm making a fetch api with jquery. Everything is normal, but when I loop inside the loop it displays [object object], and when I log into the nested loop the data is normal.
this my json

```
[
  {
    "Title": "Bla Bla",    
    "Author": "Feng Qi Yue",
    "Artist": "Feng Qi Yue",
    "User": {
      "ID": 1,
      "CreatedAt": "2021-02-23T11:16:10.722+07:00",
      "UpdatedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "Username": "soel30",
      "Password": "blablbalbala",
      "UserRefer": 1
    },
     "Genre": [
        {
        "ID": 1,
        "CreatedAt": "2021-02-23T09:42:38.681+07:00",
        "UpdatedAt": "2021-02-23T09:42:38.681+07:00",
        "DeletedAt": null,
        "Name": "Adventure",
        "Slug": "adventure"
      },
  }
]
```

and this my jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            var url = "http://someurl"
            fetch(url)
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => {
                    $.each(data, function(i, k) {
                        $("tbody.list").append(`
                        <tr>
                            <td>`+ data[i].Title + `</td>
                            <td>`+ data[i].User.Username +`</td>
                            <td>` + data[i].Author + `</td>
                            <td>`+  data[i].Artist +`</td>
                            <td>`+  $.each(data[i].Genre, function(o, l) { data[i].Genre[o].Name })
                                 +`</td> //the problem is here
                            <td>`+  data[i].Release +`</td>
                            </tr>
                        `)
                    })
                })
        }
```

Comment: @Barmar I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Map the `Genre` array to an array of `<td>`s with the names, then join by a string, you probably want commas:

```
<td>`+  data[i].Artist +`</td>
<td>`+ data[i].Genre.map(item => item.name).join(',') + `</td>
<td>`+  data[i].Release +`</td>
```

I'd also suggest using the `${}` syntax provided by template literals to make the syntax cleaner, as well as using the second argument to `.each`'s callback - or, even shorter, invoke the array iterator:

```
// $.each(data, function(i, song) {
for (const song of data) {
    $("tbody.list").append(`
    <tr>
        <td>${song.Title + `</td>
        <td>${song.User.Username}</td>
        <td>${song.Author}</td>
        <td>${song.Artist}</td>
        <td>${song.Genre.map(item => item.name).join(', ')}</td>
        <td>${song.Release}</td>
    </tr>
    `);
}
```

Another thing to keep in mind is that direct concatenation of HTML is a security risk when the values being concatenated isn't trustworthy. So make sure the `data` is good first, or run it through an XSS cleaner.

Comment: but how to take it into words. because when I put it in the a href, it joined even though I wanted each word to have one a href. Can you explain?

Comment: If you want an `<a>`, you'll have to put that in the HTML string returned by the `.map` callback. ``item => `<a href=something>${item.name}</a>`` or something of the sort